# How does PrankTxt.com send an SMS from a fake number?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

You enter in the "to" number and any "from" number, and the text message will send from that phone number. Not even the major SMS gateways support this, as they require all sender IDs to be pre-approved. So does anyone know how they set it up to send from that particular phone number?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SMS GSM protocols, the "sender id" also called OADC (Originator Address Code) is a variable. You can put any alpha numeric string with a certain max length.

Obviously this service is abusing from this functionality which is usually used for 1) branding, 2) provide a reply path for SMS a click to call number or 3) personalizing  the sender for person-to-person. For instance Facebook uses it to put session ids, Skype to either put the user id or a user mobile number to provide a reply path.

Comment: Looks like a cool service you all are building, I'll subscribe to your email update list. Thanks!

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) to your posts.

Comment: Removed spammy tagline. Please stop advertising your products on Stack OVerflow.